# ViewPager not displaying properly

Tags: java, android

I was trying to do this,

[image]

What I made is,

[image]

I have tried `HorizontalScrollView` in `ListView`
But can't get it properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my xml

```
                   <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.android.ViewPagerContainer
                        android:id="@+id/container"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </com.android.ViewPagerContainer>
                </LinearLayout>
```

My Code is

```
  private class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private int count = values.size();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public LinearLayout instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LinearLayout llViewOuter = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        llViewOuter.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ImageView thumb_image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        thumb_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.optionnor);
        thumb_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        llViewOuter.addView(thumb_image);

        TextView tmpT = new TextView(getActivity());
        tmpT.setText(values.get(position));
        tmpT.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        llViewOuter.addView(tmpT);

        final ImageView checkBox = new ImageView(getActivity());
        checkBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.optionnor);
        checkBox.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        checkBox.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //checkbox2.setImageResource(R.drawable.option);
                checkBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.optionselected);
            }
        });
        llViewOuter.addView(checkBox);


        ((ViewPager) container).addView(llViewOuter);

        return llViewOuter;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Horizontal ListView  library https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment.

```
public class ListView<ADAPTER extends Adapter> extends AbstractAdapterView<ADAPTER,View>         
implements OnLongClickListener, OnClickListener,
OnSelectedListener, AdapterViewHandler {

public ListView(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
}

public ListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attributeSet, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected AdapterViewInitializer<View> getAdapterViewInitializer(final Context context, final AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    final Attributes attributes = new Attributes(context, attributeSet);

    final boolean isViewPager = attributes.isViewPager();
    final boolean isVerticalScroll = attributes.isVertical();
    final int cellSpacing = (int) attributes.getCellSpacing();
    final boolean isCircularScroll = attributes.isCircularScroll();
    final boolean snapToPosition = attributes.isSnapToPosition();
    final int viewPagerInterval = attributes.getViewPagerInterval();
    final SnapPosition snapPosition = attributes.getSnapPosition();
    final boolean selectOnSnap = attributes.selectOnSnap();
    final boolean selectWhileScrolling = attributes.selectWhileScrolling();
    final LayoutManagerAttributes layoutManagerAttributes = new LayoutManagerAttributes(isCircularScroll, snapToPosition, isViewPager, viewPagerInterval, snapPosition, cellSpacing, selectOnSnap, selectWhileScrolling, isVerticalScroll);

    final AdapterViewManager adapterViewManager = new AdapterViewManager();
    final ListLayoutManager listLayoutManager = new ListLayoutManager(this, this, adapterViewManager, layoutManagerAttributes);

    final AdapterViewInitializer<View> adapterViewAdapterViewInitializer = createAdapterViewInitializer(context, isViewPager, adapterViewManager, listLayoutManager, isVerticalScroll);
    return adapterViewAdapterViewInitializer;
}
```

}

Hope you like it.